# Passing variable through ssh doesnt work

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to pass a variable through a ssh connection, like this:

`working_dir="/home/user/some_dir/"`

`ssh $USER@some_host 'qsub $working_dir/some_file.txt'`

The connection itself is established, but this code gives me the following error:

`working_dir: Undefined variable.`

This could be explained, by the fact that the remote machine doesn't have the variable `$working_dir` since it was defined locally.

Is there a way of getting the value in the command locally?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using double quotes, that should evaluate the variable locally:

`ssh $USER@some_host "qsub $working_dir/some_file.txt"`

Comment: Little bash-recipe of mine: "Use single quotes only if you need to make sure the content between them should be interpreted literally."

Comment: what about when you need to expand a grep variable locally to be passed to a command remotely?

ssh qa@myremote 'find $(ls -r /home/qa/log/*.*.log | grep -vi audit | head -n 1) -type f -print | xargs grep $ERRORS'

Comment: @Dss String concatenation with varying evaluation scope: ssh user@remote 'exec $REMOTEVAR'" $LOCALVAR" (that bit between the variables is a single quote immediately followed by a double quote.)

Answer (score 3):

You are using a single-quoted string -- and I suppose variables are not interpolated inside of those.

What if you try with a **double-quoted string** ?

Like this :

```
ssh $USER@some_host "qsub $working_dir/some_file.txt"
```

With that, the `$working_dir` variable should be interpolated on your end -- and its value sent via the ssh connection.

Comment: Thank you too, for the quick reply!