# how to tail all files except one

Tags: bash, find, tail

I have log files on two directories, for simplicty I'm going to call then dir 1 and dir 2.

Let's say the user enters file.log which is located in dir1, I should tail -f all files from dir1 and dir2 except file.log. Can somebody help me with this please.

```
ssh host 'find /path/to/a/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "file*" -name "*.log" ! -name "$1" -print0 -exec tail {} \;' > /home/pl-${node}.log

ssh host 'find /path/to/a/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "file*" -name "*.out" ! -name "$1" -print0 -exec tail {} \;' > /home/pl-${node}.out
```

node is just a variable that stores 1 and 2. 
when i enter ./test file-1.log, the output is:

```
pl-1.log
Oct 21 09:15 pl-1.out
Oct 21 09:15 pl-2.log
Oct 21 09:15 pl-2.out
```

As you see all files were tailed, even though i specified file-1.log to not be tailed in argument `$1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should make it:

```
find . -type f ! -name "*dir1/file.log" -exec tail {} \;
```

That is, use `find ... -exec tail {} \;` adding the extra condition that the file does not have to be named as `file.log`.

---

#### Update

> how can i use find if the name of the file is an argument in the
>   command line.for example find . ! -type f -name "$1"

Like this, for example:

> ssh host "find /path/to/a/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'file*.log' !
>   -name \"$1\" -print0 -exec tail {} \;" > /home/pl-${node}.out

Note that I am using `find ".... -name \"$1\" ... "` because to "send" variables you need double quotes.

Comment: This finds everything that is not a file named 'file.log'.  (The ! needs to be moved)

Comment: because i dont what file it is that the user wants to supress, i don't know which directory the file is located in

Comment: Yes @WilliamPursell that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @user2864207 then instead of `*dir1/file.log` you can just write `file.log`.

Comment: how can i use find if the name of the file is an argument in the command line.for example find . ! -type f -name "$1"

Comment: Uhms, it does in my machine. Update your answer with the exact command you are using, as well as the input and output.

Comment: Please update your question so that you can format the code properly. In comments it is pretty difficult to understand code.

Comment: OK now I see. You are setting `$1` as variable. You'd better use names like `var1`, because `$1` is reserved for other matters. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416880/passing-variable-through-ssh-doesnt-work/2416896#2416896 because you want the variable to work through a `ssh` command.

Comment: i set var1="$1" and i passed $var1 instead of $1 and i also include -name "qsub $var1". but it doesn't work. I don't know what i am missing

Answer (score 8):

The following would `tail` all files from `dir1` and `dir2` except `file.log`:

```
shopt -s extglob
tail -f {dir1,dir2}/!(file.log)
```

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) provides more information about `extglob` (that enables extended pattern matching).

Comment: i have a little question. let's say my log files are located in /path/to/a/log/file, if i write tail -f /path/to/a/log/file, is it gonna tail all files inside this dir?

Comment: @user2864207 Yes, `tail -f /path/to/a/log/!(file.log)` would tail all files in the mentioned directory except `file.log`

Comment: @user2864207 In order to supply multiple directories, you could say `tail -f {/path/to/a/log,/path/to/another/log}/!(file.log)` which would exclude `file.log` in both the specified directories.

Comment: i have a syntax error for the following line of code : ssh -q rt tail -n 20 {/path/to/a/log}/!("$3") > /another/path/file 2>/dev/null &. "$3" is the argument which corresponds to the file

Comment: this is awesome :)